# in php/html using CodeIgniter, how do I limit the amount of line space a list item takes up

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-lists, character

I have a list item and the value of this string item comes from a php command, how would I limit the amount of characters in this li allowed on an actual line. E.g. say I had a variable

```
$foo = 'tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt'
```

then I have (in html)

```
<ul>
<li> <?php echo $foo; ?> </li>
</ul>
```

How would I make it so only (say) 7 characters were allowed on the line so instead of printing

```
tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
```

It would print something  like 
ttttttt
ttttttt
ttttttt
etc etc.

Comment: so what happens? if the text would overflow to 7, so it would need to be on another `<li>`?

Comment: no it just goes onto a new line, I can do this via div widths but I would rather avoid it :l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use css wordwrap:

```
<style>
ul {width:30px;}
li.wrap{word-wrap: break-word;}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</li>
    <li class="wrap">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</li>
</ul>
```

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3kd8xhyz/

Or if you want a php only solution use `str_split` and `implode`:

```
$a = 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff';

echo implode(PHP_EOL, str_split($a, 7));
```

Here the constant `PHP_EOL` is used to insert carriage returns every 7 chars. You could instead use a space `' '` or an html line break `'<br>'` depending on requirements

Live example:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/iCbNJQ

Answer (score 1):

```
$len = strlen($foo); $i = 0;
while($len>0){
echo substr($foo, $i, 7)."<br>";
$i += 7;
$len -=7;
}
```